# How to flatten a multi level XML into a single level XML using c# code LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I went through certain posts about flattening an XML structure so every element and it's values were turned into attributes on the root element. However, my requirement is to flatten the input XML as per the below example for which I could not find any help.

I have got an XML structure like below,

```
<RATES ID="1" RatesEffectivateDate="27/02/2014">
  <Type Name="Type1" Code="A">
    <Del ID="D1">
      <Field1>10</Field1>
      <Field2>20</Field2>
      <Field3>30</Field3>
      <Field4>40</Field4>
    </Del>
    <Del ID="D2">
      <Field1>50</Field1>
      <Field2>60</Field2>
      <Field3>70</Field3>
      <Field4>80</Field4>
    </Del>
  </Type>
  <Type Name="Type2" Code="B">
    <Del ID="D1">
      <Field1>110</Field1>
      <Field2>120</Field2>
      <Field3>130</Field3>
      <Field4>140</Field4>
    </Del>
    <Del ID="D3">
      <Field1>150</Field1>
      <Field2>160</Field2>
      <Field3>170</Field3>
      <Field4>180</Field4>
    </Del>
  </Type>
</RATES>
```

This needs to be normalised to the format below,

```
<RATES>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type1</ID>
    <Code>A</Code>
    <DelID>D1</DelID>
    <Field1>10</Field1>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type1</ID>
    <Code>A</Code>
    <DelID>D1</DelID>
    <Field2>20</Field2>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type1</ID>
    <Code>A</Code>
    <DelID>D1</DelID>
    <Field3>30</Field3>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type1</ID>
    <Code>A</Code>
    <DelID>D1</DelID>
    <Field4>40</Field4>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type1</ID>
    <Code>A</Code>
    <DelID>D2</DelID>
    <Field1>50</Field1>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type1</ID>
    <Code>A</Code>
    <DelID>D2</DelID>
    <Field2>60</Field2>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type1</ID>
    <Code>A</Code>
    <DelID>D2</DelID>
    <Field3>70</Field3>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type1</ID>
    <Code>A</Code>
    <DelID>D2</DelID>
    <Field4>80</Field4>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type2</ID>
    <Code>B</Code>
    <DelID>D1</DelID>
    <Field1>110</Field1>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type2</ID>
    <Code>B</Code>
    <DelID>D1</DelID>
    <Field2>120</Field2>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type2</ID>
    <Code>B</Code>
    <DelID>D1</DelID>
    <Field3>130</Field3>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type2</ID>
    <Code>B</Code>
    <DelID>D1</DelID>
    <Field4>140</Field4>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type2</ID>
    <Code>B</Code>
    <DelID>D3</DelID>
    <Field1>50</Field1>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type2</ID>
    <Code>B</Code>
    <DelID>D3</DelID>
    <Field2>160</Field2>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type2</ID>
    <Code>B</Code>
    <DelID>D3</DelID>
    <Field3>170</Field3>
  </RATE>
  <RATE>
    <ID>Type2</ID>
    <Code>B</Code>
    <DelID>D3</DelID>
    <Field4>180</Field4>
  </RATE>
</RATES>
```

Please suggest on this as I am new to LINQ. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are any build-in functions to flaten the XML, but I'm very concerned they can fit your needs, because some attributes must be ignored according to your example.

You better use LINQ to XML which allows transforming such documents very easy and with not a lot of code. See my solution:

```
string origXml = "<RATES ID=\"1\" RatesEffectivateDate=\"27/02/2014\">\n  <Type Name=\"Type1\" Code=\"A\">\n    <Del ID=\"D1\">\n      <Field1>10</Field1>\n      <Field2>20</Field2>\n      <Field3>30</Field3>\n      <Field4>40</Field4>\n    </Del>\n    <Del ID=\"D2\">\n      <Field1>50</Field1>\n      <Field2>60</Field2>\n      <Field3>70</Field3>\n      <Field4>80</Field4>\n    </Del>\n  </Type>\n  <Type Name=\"Type2\" Code=\"B\">\n    <Del ID=\"D1\">\n      <Field1>110</Field1>\n      <Field2>120</Field2>\n      <Field3>130</Field3>\n      <Field4>140</Field4>\n    </Del>\n    <Del ID=\"D3\">\n      <Field1>150</Field1>\n      <Field2>160</Field2>\n      <Field3>170</Field3>\n      <Field4>180</Field4>\n    </Del>\n  </Type>\n</RATES>";
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(origXml);

var resDoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("RATES",
                    xDoc.Element("RATES")
                        .Elements("Type")
                        .SelectMany(typeEl =>
                                    typeEl.Elements("Del")
                                        .SelectMany(delEl =>
                                                    delEl.Elements()
                                                        .Select(fieldEl =>
                                                                new XElement("RATE",
                                                                                new XElement("ID", typeEl.Attribute("Name").Value),
                                                                                new XElement("Code", typeEl.Attribute("Code").Value),
                                                                                new XElement("DelID", delEl.Attribute("ID").Value),
                                                                                new XElement(fieldEl.Name, fieldEl.Value)))))
        ));

resDoc.Save("transformedDoc.xml", SaveOptions.None);
```

The output is exactly what you provided for your example.

Comment: you said, _not a lot of code_  but I see the opposite.

Comment: @Selman22, looks like we have different meaning of "not a lot of code" =). If I implemented it with old-style XmlDocument class - that would be a lot of code.

Comment: yeah you are absolutely right about that :) I just wanted to say it can be done with less code using linq, see my answer.anyway your code also works and produces the expected result.

Comment: @Selman22, your code works fine as well - I was first who upvoted it. Though it doesn't look very stable (I had plenty of unexpected mistakes using Descendants() method - that's why I don't like it; StartsWith() for element name is even more dangerous). It's even not taking into consideration performance of always accessing .Parent.Parent. So I don't consider my slightly longer solution worse.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("path");

var rates = new List<XElement>();

foreach (var type in xmlDocument.Descendants("Type"))
{
    foreach (var del in type.Elements("Del"))
    {
          foreach (var field in del.Elements())
          {
              XElement rate = new XElement("RATE",
                        new XElement("ID", (string) type.Attribute("Name")),
                        new XElement("Code", (string) type.Attribute("Code")),
                        new XElement("DelID", (string) del.Attribute("ID")),
                        new XElement(field.Name, (string) field));
              rates.Add(rate);
          }
    }
}

XElement root = new XElement("RATES");
root.Add(rates);
root.Save("newFile.xml");
```

Another way using `LINQ` instead of loops but I think this is less readable

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("path");

var newXML = new XElement("RATES",
            xmlDocument.Descendants()
                .Where(x => x.Name.ToString().StartsWith("Field"))
                .Select(
                    x =>
                        new XElement("RATE",
                            new XElement("ID", (string) x.Parent.Parent.Attribute("Name")),
                            new XElement("Code", (string) x.Parent.Parent.Attribute("Code")),
                            new XElement("DelID", (string) x.Parent.Attribute("ID")),
                            new XElement(x.Name, (string) x))));

newXML.Save("newFile.xml");
```